# Is there a general rule that will tell you the order of a set ($\mathbb{Z}_p^*$)$^n$ for some n?

Tags: number-theory

I am learning about quadratic residues in an elementary number theory class, and I know that for a prime p the set ($\mathbb{Z}_p^*$)$^2$ has an order of $\frac{p-1}{2}$, so half of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ are quadratic residues and the other half are not, but is there a general way of knowing how many elements are in a set if it is taken to a power greater than two?

For example:

$\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} order of 6

($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^2$ = {1, 2, 4} order of $\frac{7-1}{2} = 3$

($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^3$ = {1, 6} order of 2

($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^4$ = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6} order of 6

My question is would there be a general rule that lets you know the order of the sets ($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^3$ or ($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^4$? Also is there a way of knowing which elements would be in ($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^3$ or ($\mathbb{Z}_7^*$)$^4$ without actually calculating each element in $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ to the third or fourth power?

Comment: For prime $p$, the set of $k$-th powers has $\frac{p-1}{\gcd(p-1,k)}$ elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prime $p$, the set of non-zero $k$-th powers modulo $p$ has $\frac{p-1}{\gcd(p-1,k)}$ elements.

The easiest way to see this is by using the fact that any prime $p$ has a primitive root $g$. Let $d=\gcd(p-1,k)$. We show that the set of non-zero $k$-th powers modulo $p$  is precisely the set of all $g^{di}$ modulo $p$, where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $\frac{p-1}{d}$.

First we show that any $g^{di}$ is a $k$-th power. Since $\gcd(p-1,k)=d$, by the Bezout "Identity" there are integers $s$ and $t$ such that $s(p-1)+tk=d$.  Thus
$$g^d=(g^{p-1})^s (g^t)^k\equiv (g^t)^k \pmod{p}.$$
It follows that $g^d$ is a $k$-th power, and therefore so is $g^{di}$.

The other direction is easier. Let $b$ be a non-zero $k$-th power. Then $b\equiv (g^j)^k\pmod{p}$ for some $j$. But then since $d$ divides $k$, it follows that $b$ is congruent to a power of $g^d$.